# Custom App Page Change Site Title, pass new Title value

Tags: development

I created a custom app page with two user controls:
asp:TextBox ID="SiteTitle" runat="server"   and 
asp:Button ID="UpdateSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update"

The goal is to have the same behavior as the _layouts/prjsetng.aspx page
So checking the current Title, change it and update it.

For some reason the below code is not updating the title. (Rights are ok running this as site col admin)

Code behind:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
       string Title = SPContext.Current.Web.Title;
       SiteTitle.Text = Title;
```

UpdateSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateSubmitButton_Click);
}

private void UpdateSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPWeb oweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            oweb.Title = SiteTitle.Text.ToString();
            oweb.Update();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page_Load fires before UpdateSubmitButton_Click

I would refactor your code to be:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    UpdateSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateSubmitButton_Click);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostBack) {
        DataBind(SPContext.Current.Web):
    }
}

public void DataBind(SPWeb web) {
    SiteTitle.Text = web.Title;
}

private void UpdateSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SPWeb oweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    oweb.Title = SiteTitle.Text.ToString();
    oweb.Update();
    DataBind(oweb);
}
```

1. Always try to bind your event handlers as early as possible (OnInit)
2. Bind control values in a databind event
3. In OnLoad have a IsPostBack clause to prevent double DataBinds
4. After events, databind the new values

Comment: Thanks for pushing me on the right track!
- VS2010 throws an error on the OnInit: Method must have a return type

Comment: ah missing a "void"

Comment: Thanks... Now I've an error "no suitable method found to override" on the OnInit one...

Comment: remove sender arguement